# honda accord takes a while to start/intermittently stalls

Tags: honda, starting, accord

My 99 honda accord takes a while to start when its cold also it intermittently stalls while driving. The rotor and cap, fuel filter and pump was both replaced. other then that it runs fine. I have no clue what is going on. please give me some answers.

Comment: have you checked the plugs and leads?

Comment: Hondas are known to have fuel pump relay problems. When it won't start turn the key to on and listen for the fuel pump to run for about 5 seconds and then it should shut off.

Comment: @mikes Any chance you can post your answer-comment as an answer? This beta is [light on answers](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1321/motor-vehicle-maintenance-and-repair).

Comment: As @mikes suggests, but you'll only hear the pump on the first key turn in the morning after pressure has bled off of the system. Once you've turned it on for the first time, you'll probably not hear the pump for a while even with turning the key from off to on.

Comment: Do you have the V6 accord? or the 2.3L 4 Cylinder?

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you have a condition that presents itself like this i.e. "Runs fine when accelerator is depressed" and or "Dies at stop lights, but functions normally at all other times". It's a bit difficult to diagnose. From personal experience and many years working as a master-tech for Honda/ Acura, the throttle position sensor and upstream o2 sensors are the common cause for a stalling condition. You need a good scan tool and some good diagnostic equipment to properly weed out the issue.

If you have a basic scan tool that you would obtain from an auto parts store, you can look at o2 voltages and fuel trims. Your fuel trims and o2 data will send you in the right direction.

When diagnosing the vehicle you need to eliminate one by one, the major components that allow a combustion engine to function. "Fuel, Air, spark, timing and compression".

If your fuel pressure is low for some reason the car won't run right. If you have a vacuum leak, it will not operate. There are several sensors and solenoids on that vehicle that control idle engine RPM and deceleration of the RPM. If they aren't sending proper information to the ECU, the car will not run right.
Diagnosing this over the internet is almost impossible without constant feedback from you. I would not suggest tightening the head bolts or fiddling with your valves if you're not VERY familiar with Honda/ Acura procedure. The J series, K series and B series engines are complicated unless you're practiced at working with them.

I don't see how an alternator can cause this?....
Once an alternator goes bad, your car relies solely on the battery. Once the car uses up the juice in the battery, the car will not start, run or do anything for that matter. Hard starting and stalling are not first symptoms of a bad alternator. You can goto a local parts store and they will test your charging system and battery for free.

Answer (score -1):

The slow start in the winter time is usually due to complications in the fuel rail, simply valve wear or the fact that they may loosen or tighten over the years, or years of fuel injector clogging. Here are some things you can do to fix these problems. When you say it is dying while driving that would be your alternator. When it goes bad, it doesn't charge your battery. When your battery goes bad. Your spark plugs will not ignite.

- When you start your car try turning it on and off three times, slowly, pump the gas the third time it's on, and turn it off again. Then start it. This primes your fuel injectors with fuel. This will also work when you're very low on gas.
- Look into adjusting your valves with a feeler gauge(cont..). They're located right under the valve cover or engine cover.  If you're careful, you can even tighten or loosen them evenly by literally quarter or half turns at a time. Too tight and it will be liked a choked weed eater, hard to start. Too loose and you will hear the valves clicking against the valve seals. Just right and it should be quiet, or it will sound similar to a diesel engine.
- Take off you're valve cover and use a breaker bar, to hand tighten your head bolts/studs. These tighten your engines head, with the block underneath, keeping oil, antifreeze, and cylinder fire from leaking out. Check the bolt torque specs unless you have a lot of experience. On a small 4 cylinder car it's about 40- 60 lbs. on each head bolt, 6-8 count, giving you about 300- 400 lbs. of constant force holding the motor shut. V-6's and V-8's will have two valve covers, because they have two camshafts that run the valves like a music box. Some old chevy's you can adjust while it's running. Don't do that or it will splash molten oil in your face. Also before touching head bolts, let motor cool down for 5 hours.
- If you have a spark plug that is not all the way in or out, you can try, carefully while the engine is still warm or hot, because that may be how it was siezed or was cross threaded to begin with. Any broken bolts besides the valve cover could cost you hundred of dollars to fix or have rethreaded.
- Take off your fuel rail and use a 9 volt battery to open it. Run break cleaner through the injectors if applicable.

Comment: I agree with your thoughts on the fuel related parts. The other suggestions don't really apply to Honda/Acura.